# django objects.filter exclude yourself

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Handling uniqueness in the code in Django, I've found a problem: How to check records at validators, but excluding yourself, because the update function?

I've trying below, but doesn't works.

Please, Could you help me?

model.py

```
def check_email_person(email_given):
    myid = Person.id
    if Person.objects.filter(email=email_given).exclude(id__in=myid):
       raise ValidationError(u"E-mail already exists!")

class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[check_email_person])
```

Comment: Why not just set `unique=True` on the email field?

Comment: Hi Brandon, because blank e-mails are allowed. Tks.

Comment: You can set unique=True and blank=True. The field validator will only be fired if a value is present.

Comment: In Django-Admin unique=True and blank=True, doesn't working as you said. So, unfortunately I need handling uniqueness in the code. Tks.

Comment: How so? If you set unique=True and blank=True, you won't need to have the additional validator, and the properties should work as expected in admin.

Comment: Brandon, if I set unique=True and blank=True, django-admin don't allow 2 records with blank e-mail. So, I can't to use unique=True and, exactly for this, that I need check duplicate e-mail with validator. Tks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do something like this in the form validation:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    try:
        User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return email
    raise forms.ValidationError('duplicate_email')
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that is to have `unique=True` on `email` field as `Brandon` suggested. But for now your problem can be solved as:

```
def check_email_person(email_given):
    myid = Person.id
    if Person.objects.filter(email=email_given).exclude(id=myid):
       raise ValidationError(u"E-mail already exists!")
```

You don't need to use `__in` on id as it is just a single id.

Comment: Hi Aamir, I've tried this too, but doesn't works! I receive message that id does not exist in Person, however It is there. Tks!

Comment: `Person` is also the model name. I don't see how you are passing `Person` model object in `check_email_person`. So `Person.id` is wrong as django will try to get `id` attribute from `Person` class model.

Answer (score 0):

`__in` requires a list to check. Try

```
Person.objects.filter(email=email_given).exclude(id__in=[myid])
```

Comment: `id=myid` would give the same result